# arguments to javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments

```
var data = [{offset: 2000, str:'foo'}, {offset: 4000, str:'bar'}];

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var x = data[i];
    setTimeout(function(){printStuff(x.str)}, x.offset);
}

function printStuff(str) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

I was expecting to get `printStuff('foo')` at 2000 ms offset and `printStuff('bar')` at 4000 ms offset but instead it prints 'bar' both times. I've no idea what's going on, help please.

Comment: it's a scoping issue; when your `printStuff` finally runs, `x` has been reassigned to `{offset:4000,str:'bar'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    (function (x) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            printStuff(x.str)
        }, x.offset);
    })(data[i]);
}
```

Your problem is that x has changed in the closure when the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functional iteration that gives a closure for free:

```
data.forEach( function( x ) {
      setTimeout( printStuff.bind(null, x.str), x.offset );
});
```

Shims for all in case oldIE support is required:

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: I didn't knew this new and interesting function. Do you have precision about the compatibility (including mobiles) ?

Comment: @dystroy the compatibility and user-made code to make those functions work in unsupported browsers can be found in the links I gave. Roughly any browser made/patched after december 2009 should support them.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` does not block the code from continuing to execute, so the loop completes, and by the time the `setTimeout` callback is executed, the latest value for 'x' is the second object in the `data` array.